# jQuery - Fixed navigation menu with variable height according to the scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new in jQuery and it's been a few days that I'm trying to make a top-fixed navigation menu in my page with variable height according to the scroll, but so far it has been a struggle to figure out how this works. I managed to kinda simulate the effect with just CSS Transition but it's not what I want.

Here a perfect exemple of what I'm trying to accomplish: www.bulo.com
and here: http://d.pr/i/fqaB

I examined the code of Bulo.com, and find it really hard to comprehend, since the part that apparently make it all works, it's inside jQuery.js and it's all compressed with no spaces or linebreaks whatsoever, making me go bananas.

I stripped down what I thought it's important:

HTML:

```
<header class="mod-header" data-target-padding="40">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="collections.html">Collections</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="for-sale.html">For sale</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.mod-header {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
z-index: 901;
}
.mod-header .navigation {
text-align: center;
}
.mod-header .navigation ul {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.mod-header .navigation li {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 18px;
margin: 0;
overflow: visible;
padding: 64px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 910;
}
.mod-header .navigation li a {
color: #171617;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
height: 18px;
margin: 0 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
.mod-header.mod-header-fixed {
left: 0;
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Not going to post the jquery.js files because it's freaking gigantic, but you can easily see it for yourself with Firebug or Inspect Element in Safari.

So, can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to add a class `mod-header-fixed` to that navigation bar just when the page *70px* scrolled down and then remove it when the page is scrolled back.

The following jQuery example would easily catch that kind of event and do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70){
            $(".navigation").addClass("mod-header-fixed");
         } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 70) {
            $(".navigation").removeClass("mod-header-fixed");
         }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/svVxa/)

Read more about `.scrollTop()` method on [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

#### EDIT 1:

You said that you can't read compressed code? Please, just copy/paste the code you can't read in to [JavaScript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and get read-friendly version of it!

#### EDIT 2:

If you want the object to change `.height()` you could manipulate *padding* property using `.animate()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70){
             $(".navigation").addClass("mod-header-fixed");
             $(".mod-header .navigation li").stop().animate({ 
                padding: "45px 0"
             }, 600 );
             $(".mod-header .navigation li").stop().animate({ 
                padding: "45px 0"
             }, 600 );
         } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 70) {
             $(".navigation").removeClass("mod-header-fixed");
             $(".mod-header .navigation li").stop().animate({ 
                padding: "15px 0"
             }, 600 );
             $(".mod-header .navigation li").stop().animate({ 
                padding: "15px 0"
             }, 600 );
         }
     });
 });
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XT9su/)

Comment: I'm afraid I was not clear explaining exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Here: http://d.pr/i/fqaB

Comment: The code I made for you can add a class *mod-header-fixed*  to *.navigation* object, when the page is scrolled down. Then obviously you could do other manipulations with it, on the basic CSS menu  proprties.

Comment: Hello again Illia, thanks for your reply. Ok, it works but I still can't figure out how to do the animation part...

Comment: @Adonai, just updated my answer for you to make menu change height on scrolling.

Comment: @Illia, it works but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do. Your code just triggers the animation when the page is scrolled X pixels. What I need is, if my nav menu is 200px and the user scrolls just 10 pixels, the nav menu bar will be 190px, if he scrolls 37px, then the nav bar will be 163px of height... scrolls 5000px, then the nav bar will be at a minimum height of 50px. If the user scroll all the way back to the top, the nav bar return to his original state, 200px. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough, my english is not so good... And thanks again for being so helpful with my learning.

Comment: Take a look at this example, I hope it's what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/X5gKT/

Comment: @Illia, it still only trigger the animation, which is not what I want. Did you take a look at the .gif I posted? http://d.pr/i/fqaB That .gif illustrates EXACTLY what I want.

Comment: @Adonal I have provided you with very basic example that refers directly to your problem. Achieving it is something you should do yourself. It takes time but when you learn you might really enjoy it!